# GKE: Very large URI of GET request can not hit nginx-ingress (no logs)

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, google-kubernetes-engine, nginx-ingress

For reporting, my application transfer data via URI, in some cases, it'll make the URI very long (GET request) (example: ~15.000 characters encoded).

In this situation, I test with differences proxy as below:

- (1) with `nginx-ingress` in GKE: the client is not receive response from web server, also **no log** found in `nginx-ingress` (added annotations: `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/large-client-header-buffers: "4 16k"` and `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/client-body-buffer-size: "5m"`)
- (2) with `nginx` run on VM: OK (added in config: `large_client_header_buffers 4 16k;`

Because there is no log info in `nginx-ingress` service, I think the connection may be dropped by Google firewall or something else before it can come to `nginx-ingress`.

How can I debug in this case to find the problem? Are there any documents about the URL length allowed in GKE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using 15000 characters which are highly larger due to this GET request cannot hit the logs.
As per Google Cloud [official doc](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/http#long_request_urls),

> The URL has a **practical length limitation, typically between 2k to 8k.**
> It's enforced by some browsers and proxies. If your API uses GET
> requests with URLs that exceed the length limitation, such requests
> may be rejected by browsers. **To bypass the limitation, the client code
> should use a POST request with Content-Type of
> application/x-www-form-urlencoded along with HTTP header
> X-HTTP-Method-Override: GET**. This approach also works for DELETE
> requests.

- So, by  this use POST request instead of GET generally POST will take
  higher value. It allows you to send data to the request body instead of URI. Refer to [doc](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp) for more information.
- Or Try by adding the below snippet in the Ingress controller yaml and have a check this is one of the work around :

  > ```
  > nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
  >   http2_max_header_size 256k;
  >   http2_max_field_size 256k;
  > ```
- There is currently an existing [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35892557) for increasing this
  length; this will change in the near future. You can 'star' the issue
  to get further updates and/or provide your use case in the comments.

Comment: Update, tried with snippet but nothing changed.